# Loops in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, syntax, oracle11g

I'm new to all of this oracle stuff and I was wondering if you can help.

I'm trying to write something that will output the message "hello" n times. Where n is a variable that's chosen.

I want to use a for loop, but not sure how it would look.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: But why? SQL isn't about loops and printing hello messages.

Comment: I'm starting off from basics, the training that im doing asked me to do this. But because i'm self learning i wanted to start simple.

Comment: I've never needed to something like that, in 20+ years...

Comment: That's what it's asked me to do, the actual question is: 
Write a function or  Declare BEGIN, END block that will output a message “Hi” x times where x is some variable you choose

Comment: @jarlh That's my instinctive reaction, but PL/SQL does have a lot more of that stuff than most dialects. Traditionally, Oracle shops tend to lean more in the direction of implementing business logic and other operations that aren't very set-based on the database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BEGIN
FOR I IN 1..20
LOOP
   dbms_output.put_line('Value of I is :- ' || I);
END LOOP;
END;
```

For more information on for loop you can check this site - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1536

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it :)

Comment: PLease mark this answer as correct answer if it helped you. :)